# How to create 2d trajectory by moving mouse over plot

Tags: plotting, interactive, dynamic

When I move with the mouse over a plot with a given plot range I would like to store the coordinates of the corresponding trajectory in a list and plot it.

I have seen that `MousePosition` is used to read the current mouse position in the notebook, but I do not how to start.

Answer (score 6):

The following works:

```
mymouse := Block[{}, pos = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
              If[pos =!= None, AppendTo[posList, pos]]]
posList = {};
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]; (* your plot *)

Dynamic[Show[plot, ListLinePlot[posList, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
Dynamic[mymouse]
```

[image]

(This amazing artwork is copyrighted ©anderstood)

**Edit** Maybe this is a bit smoother?

```
mymouse := Block[{}, pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
  If[pos =!= None, AppendTo[posList, pos];
         posList = DeleteDuplicates@posList;]]
(* If[pos =!= None && Not@MemberQ[postList,pos], AppendTo[posList, pos]; *) 
posList = {};
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}];(*your plot*)Dynamic[
 Show[plot, ListLinePlot[posList, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
Dynamic[mymouse]
```

And this to avoid the slow `AppendTo`:

```
i = 1;
mymouse := Block[{}, pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
  If[pos =!= None, posList[[i]] = pos; i++;]]
posList = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, 1000];
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}];(*your plot*)Dynamic[
 Show[plot, ListLinePlot[posList, PlotStyle -> Red]]]
Dynamic[mymouse]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works good, but somehow my on my computer it is very slow: when I move the mouse I have to wait a while to see the curve. Can you also observe this? Another problem: if the mouse is not moved the code continuously stores the same coordinate. Can the code store only once this coordinates? PS: Nobody will be able exactly to repeat your copyrighted artwork, it is unique ;-)

Comment: @lio I edited, is it better? I tried on two PCs and is was OK, not perfect but OK. To improve that, you would need someone more knowledgeable than me... `AppendTo` is not recommended but I do not see how to avoid that. I added a third possibility just to see if its smoother, but it introduces the point `{0, 0}`.

Comment: This is excellent for a project I am currently working on; I did not know about MousePosition!  Is there an easy way to make this start recording points on the path after a mouseclick, and end after clicking again?

Comment: @Steve I don't have MMA readily available to try it, but I would start by reading https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[addLines]
addLines = DynamicModule[{lc, t = .01, nps = NewPrimitiveStyle /.
       Options[$FrontEnd, NewPrimitiveStyle]},
 Column[{Row[{Button["add lines", FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEnd`Select2DTool["DrawFreehand", "Persistent" -> True]], Alignment -> Center],
  Panel@ColorSetter[Dynamic[lc, (lc = #; SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
     NewPrimitiveStyle -> {nps = nps /. Rule[LineColor, _] :> Rule[LineColor, #]}]) &],
     BaselinePosition -> Scaled[1/4]],
  Panel@Labeled[LabeledSlider[Dynamic[t, ((t = #; SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
     NewPrimitiveStyle -> {nps = nps /. Rule[Thickness, _] :>  Rule[Thickness, #]}])) &], 
    {0, 1/10, 1/100}, ImageMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False], "thickness", Left]},
 Spacer[1], Alignment -> Center], #}]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
addLines[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image]

```
addLines[BarChart[Range[10], ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image]

**See also:** [tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html)

Comment: Great use of `"DrawFreehand"`! However I think your drawing skills lack originality. It's too much copied from Otto Zitko.

Comment: @anderstood,  my "drawings skills" :)

Comment: How  to store the coordinates of the corresponding trajectory in a list ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, I don't know an easy way to modify this to get the coordinates. I will update if I come up with a solution.

Comment: @kglr. Ok. Thanks for reply. :)

Comment: This is great and very fast, but I need to access the coordinates. It would be great if that would be possible.